# Is Docker volumes content actually copied from host to container or not?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

When I do something like this in `docker compose`:

```yaml
  volumes:
    - ./host_config:/container_config
```

does Docker actually copy the content of `host_config` to the container folder `container_config` (meaning that the storage used size on the machine is actually increased by the size of the shared folder) or just "link" files?

I'm asking this because in my case `host_config` is like **100GB** and I would not want the content of it to be really copied to the container (I know that the volumes are stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` so I dont want that folder to have additional 100GB on my machine).

I've read https://docs.docker.com/storage/ but it's still not clear to me that part I'm asking, could anyone please better explain that to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does Docker actually copy the content of host_config to the container folder container_config

No.

> or just "link" files?

No.

> could anyone please better explain that to me?

Research "mount bind". This is exactly what docker actually does. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: *since the two views show the same data* from the link you provided is what I needed to see, I guess! Thank you